# Не работает вызов функций

Tags: python

```
obychenie = print('Обучение: После любых вопросов, Вы должны написать: A, B, C, D, Y, N, a, b, c, d, y, n. Ещё вариантов ответа ответа может быть не четыре а допустим три. Ещё если вы напишите что-то другое, игра будет завершена!')
inp = input('Вы хотите продолжить?(y/n): ')

def dtxt():
    txt = print('\n   Вы снова попали в имперскую тюрьму за карманую кражу. Обычно когда Вы отсидели месяц за такое, и Вас отпускали.')
    txt2 = print('Но на этот раз что-то не так, и Вы продолжаете сидеть в этом гнилом месте.')
    txt3 = print('Напротив вашей камеры, стоит заключённый. Он смотрит на Вас как обычно, как-то косо. Всё потому что Вы уже не первый, не второй и даже не третий раз здесь находитесь.')
    txt4 = print('Вы даже знаете что он сидит за попытку убить Императора. Хотя обычно за такое казнь, но его посадили просто пожизненно!')
    txt5 = print('А вот имени его Вы не знаете. Наверное потому что никогда в голову не приходило спросить. Хотя даже не логично немного, сидите не первый раз по месяцу и не знаете имени человека напротив')
    txt6 = print('Что по охране? Иногда проходит мимо камер и смотрит чтобы всё было впорядке.')
    txt7 = print('Как раз когда будет проходить, спрошу что на счёт меня?')
    txt8 = print('А сейчас нужно решить, ждать охрану или поговорить c заключённым...')
    txt9 = print('\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\n')

def ifelse():    
    if inp == 'y':
        dtxt()
    else:
        quit
ifelse()

def a1():
    print('A: Подойти к заключённому')
    print('B: Ждать охрану.')

def a2():
    input('Выберите ответ: ')

def a3():
    print('Вы подошли к заключённому.')

def a4():
    print('Вы ждёте охрану.')

if a2 == "a":
    print(a3)
elif a2 == "b":
    print(a4)
else:
    quit


a1()
a2()
```

После ввода в `ifelse()` буквы `"y"` проходят функции  `dtxt`, `a1`, `a2`. После ввода ответа на вопрос в функцию `a2`, а именно `a` или `b`, ничего не происходит. А должно при вводе `"a"` переходить на функцию `a3` и писать текст. Так же с функцией `a4`.
Если ещё проще, то всё работает кроме функций `a3` и `a4`.

Answer (score 0):

Возвращайте введённый ответ из функции a2 и записывайте его в переменную. А после этого сравнивайте его и вызывайте соответствующие функции.

```
def a1():
    print('A: Подойти к заключённому')
    print('B: Ждать охрану.')

def a2():
    return input('Выберите ответ: ')

def a3():
    print('Вы подошли к заключённому.')

def a4():
    print('Вы ждёте охрану.')

answer = a2()
if answer == "a":
    a3()
elif answer == "b":
    a4()
else:
    quit()
```

Comment: После замены всё тоже самое

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: А можете объяснить, почему именно answer и почему не работает если заменить print на вызов функции? Должно же в теории.

Comment: @marks, когда вы пишете a1, a2, a3, вы не вызываете эти функции. Функции вызываются с помощью скобок.Поэтому здесь if a2 == "a": сравнение было написано неправильно. Чтобы получить результат работы функции, надо вернуть из неё значение и записать в переменную.